# Vertices not working?

Tags: vertices, edges

When I try to add to my plain by selecting two vertices and then pressing E it only extends the edges and not the entire plain how does one fix this?
https://gyazo.com/b46b4cd4c2bf68e416e14fb32ffef16b

Comment: The most common cause of this is the impression that right-clicking after [E extrude] cancels the extrusion. It does not. It cancels the _move_ after the extrusion, leaving the duplicated elements (invisibly) in place. Use Ctrl-Z if you want to cancel the whole operation.

Comment: [How to upload an image to a post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491/how-to-upload-an-image-to-a-post)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should check if those vertices are duplicates. It looks like vertices being overlapping (2 or more in the same space). It happens a lot when trying to extrude, then "forgetting" to move your extrusion

Correct this issue in EDIT mode. Select all by hitting A, then by go to MESH menu, then choose Clean up, merge by distance. If not, there must be something you are doing wrong when extruding, but I am almost sure those are vertices overlapping.

Comment: Yup that helped thanks man appreciate the help

Comment: Just how do i stop this from happening because id have to do that every time I extent the mesh

Comment: You are duplicating the vertices. Just don't copy/extrude without paying attention. In case of doubt, use that merge vertice command.

Comment: It's *Vertex > Merge Vertices > By Distance* when you're using the menu.

Comment: I just select two of them and press e and do my thing how do i stop from copying them?

Comment: As you stated, you are "doing your thing"... Only you knows what you are doing wrong. Practice will improve your understanding of Blender and hopefully you won't have this issue anymore.